# String.ElementAt() does not work in Windows 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am struggling to find any resources to explain why the following code does not exist in windows 8 apps(i hate using ToCharArray, i am far too lazy for that).

```
    encoded.ElementAt(z)==';'
```

This code works perfectly in my desktop version yet it doesn't for the app.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: windows tablet/device framework doesn't have all the features that full windows x86 framework does

Comment: "Yes it doesn't work". What do you mean by that? Does it not compile? Does it throw a runtime exception? Is it aways false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you might be working with a string, since you mentioned `ToCharArray`. If so, you can just use the indexer to get the character:

```
char result = encoded[z];
```

Comment: Thank you. works like magic.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you simply forgot `using System.Linq;` at the top of your *.cs file, because according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx) this method is supported in Windows Store Apps:

> .NET for Windows Store apps
>   Supported in: Windows 8

Comment: I would also bet on this one